# Common name for words like duplicate, triplicate, quadruplicate etc

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a list of words that I can sort by name. The list might also contain duplicates, triplicates, quadruplicates etc. The list can also be sorted in such a way that such repetitions show up on time. What should I call this sort mode?
"Sort by Duplicity" is the closest I could get. But I was told that it is usually used in a negative sense.
I'm looking for alternate suggestions that would ideally be a single word.

Comment: *multiplicity*? You mean that terms that appear 4 times come before terms thay appear 3 times, and so on, right?

Comment: *Sort by appearances* or *instances* is far more natural that whatever word might fit the exact request...

Comment: *Duplicity* would be related to being *duplicitous*... *two-faced*.  Not what you're looking for.

Comment: Unix programs call this sorting by *count*, but I'm not sure I love that nomenclature.

Comment: If you dont like the other suggestions, maybe multiplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a single word, "sort by *frequency*" sounds the most natural to me:

> the number, proportion, or percentage of items in a particular category in a set of data

<sub>(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frequency))</sub>

"Sort by number of appearances/instances" works as well but is a few words longer; what @lly suggests is technically speaking not complete (but will certainly be understood by most users).

Answer (score 2):

"Replicate" is a standard one word option when talking about duplicates, triplicates, etc. So if you're wanting to name a column that you can sort by, I would name the column Replicate.

Answer (score 1):

**Find the dupes.**

"Dupes" stands for *duplicates*.

This is the standard way one talks about duplicate records in a database.